# New Relic Java Installation for Confluence

Tags: java, newrelic, confluence

I'm trying to install New Relic on an Ubuntu 14.04 server, to monitor a Confluence installation on the same server. When I try and run the installer, I get:

```
***** ( ( o))  New Relic Java Agent Installer

***** Installing version 3.22.0 ...

* Could not edit start script because:
Could not locate a Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, JBoss7 or Glassfish instance in /srv/data-confluence

* Try re-running the install command with the -s <AppServerRootDirectory> option or from <AppServerRootDirectory>/newrelic.
If that doesn't work, locate and edit the start script manually.

* No need to create New Relic configuration file because:
A config file already exists: /srv/data-confluence/newrelic/newrelic.yml

***** Install incomplete
```

I tried to manually install it by following the information here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/installation/java-agent-manual-installation and running the command for Tomcat, still no joy - same error.

Answer (score 1):

**For those who run into this same issue:**

**Wrap up**

Historical note: This is Confluence running an instance of Tomcat 8.

Luca attempted to install using the New Relic Agent self-installer. Running `java -jar newrelic.jar install` within the `/newrelic/` folder located in the Confluence home folder (in this case`/srv/atlassian-confluence/bin/`) successfully added the `-javaagent` switch to the `catalina.sh`, but then output into the console

> ***** Installing version 3.22.0 ...
>
> - Could not edit start script because: 
>     Could not locate a Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, JBoss7 or Glassfish instance in  /srv/data-confluence
> - Try re-running the install command with the -s  option or from /newrelic. 
>     If that doesn't work, locate and edit the start script manually.
> - No need to create New Relic configuration file because: 
>     A config file already exists: /srv/atlassian-confluence/newrelic/newrelic.yml
>
> ***** Install incomplete

At this point, Luca moved the `newrelic.jar` and `newrelic.yml` from `/srv/atlassian-confluence/bin/newrelic` to the folder above, namely `/srv/atlassian-confluence/bin/`.  The new relic agent attempted to start up with confluence after running the `startup-confluence.sh` startup script but was (1) unable to create a log file, and (2) caused confluence to [throw an exception](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Unable+to+startup+Confluence+with+java.net.ConnectException).

In order to remedy this situation, Luca and I needed to:

(1) Remove the multi-line switch added by new relic to `catalina.sh`

(2) Run through the [java agent manual installation instructions](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/installation/java-agent-manual-installation#Installing_on_Tomcat) but instead of putting `export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/full/path/to/newrelic.jar"` into `catalina.sh` we put it into the confluence startup script `startup-confluence.sh`.

At this point, Luca needed to run the stop and start scripts for Confluence to get the agent reporting to the New Relic APM dashboard.

The confusion herein was that the auto-installer didn't work, so the auto-installer's changes needed to be reversed and the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable set within the appropriate script.

Comment: This needs updating as per my forum comment so it's correct.